# Create column from another column with multiple values in the rows

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax, multiple-columns, powerquery

I want to filter values but the rows contain multiple values. So here is an example of what I want to create.
[image: Picture of the column]I want to create a column where rows that contain multiple values equals to 1 value.
Example:
A row that contains Konsulent, Hovedsertifisør, Hovedkonsulent, konsulent to respond to just Hovedsertifisør for example.

I tried the related dax, if else statements

Answer (score 0):

As given in your example I assume that the "," defines multiple values, not the " ".
Use this **Calculated Column**

```
Column = 
IF(
    SEARCH(",", 'Table'[Name], 1, BLANK()), 
    "Hovedsertifisør", 
    'Table'[Name]
)
```